# Concat to request before requesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a POST form in html with this structure:

name1
email1
address1

on a button press a new div with the exact same fields appears with a number higher

This data gets posted to an express function where a foreach loop is supposed to fetch the data.

The problem I am having is incrementing the req.body.name in the foreach

The following code is the closest I have gotten, however I always get a "NaN" error

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
for (var i = 1; i <= req.body.numberOfItems; i++) {
    console.log(req.body.name += i);
}}
```

Comment: Probably because req.body.name is null and you are adding a number to it. Maybe instead - console.log(req.body.name) to see what the result is, or even console.log(req.body.name, i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are incrementing the `req.body.name` value.

You should change the key only

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
for (var i = 1; i <= req.body.numberOfItems; i++) {
    console.log(req.body["name"+i]);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, worked like a charm. As I am not using an array I thought I could not change the key.

Comment: @Julius this is not an array. As you are using dynamic object keys (name1, name2, name3), you should use brackets instead of dot to specify the key on the `req.body` object